# manipulate the table locally, i.e. read the table into memory, process and then write to server

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that steps through a sheet, then updates the sheet content and adds calendar items. I noticed that the execution takes up to 3 minutes and I suspect that the server calls are the reason. This is how I access the data today.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
```

Now I wanted to make it better and manipulate the table locally, i.e. read the table into memory, process and then write to server in one go. I am sure there are plenty similar issues on SO for google apps script, if I only could get a good search term. "async bulk request" did not give me good hits on SO. Any hints on available issues or how to search for them?
Then I can start with selfstudy.

Comment: Go into the documentation and read about the difference between getValues() and getValue()

Comment: That same information is also available in best practices in the support section of the documentation

Answer (score 1):

This particular best practice is described in Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations)

According to the docs the correct way to read data from a spreadsheet, manipulate it, and then save it again is as follows:

```
function readAndWriteInBulk() {
  // read all the data in the active sheet at once with getValues()
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const data = range.getValues();
  // manipulate the data as you like
  for (const row of data) {
    // do something to a row
    Logger.log(row);
  }
  // paste the data at once in a new sheet with setValues()
  const newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.insertSheet();
  const pasteRange = newSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length);
  pasteRange.setValues(data);
}
```

**References**:

[getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))